# How to write code for view transition with animation in same activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, view, android-animation, transition

I want to write code for view transition with animation in same activity, as animation shown in above link.

So, I have a list activity of images, say it's defaultView. On each list item click, there should open a new view of only imageview of that particular image with animation. 
And when I long press on tempView it should goes back to defaultView with reverse animation.

so what should be my approach to solve the problem?

Note : [link for animation reference](http://jimulabs.com/2014/12/journey-lollipop-transitions-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLaytou>
<ListView>
<defaultView/>
</ListView>
<tempView visible = gone>
</FrameLaytou>


 defaultView click
-> view.getLocationInWindow(location) to getXY of defaultView 
-> tempView setLayoutParams to defaultView's location and defaultView'size
-> tempView visible
-> Property Animation to set tempView target positoin and target size
-> longclick 
-> Property Animation to set tempView defaultView's location and defaultView'size
-> tempView  gone
```

Comment: can you explain in detail. because i didn't get it.

Comment: Did you add the layout I metioned?Plz try do sth I metioned and update you quesition.I'm working and will be free 6 hours later.